# Как выполнить тестовое задание, требующее убрать стоящие рядом одинаковые слова за один цикл?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть такая строка. `car car was driving car was driving`;

Нужно убрать повторение стов. Но только те которые следуют друг за другом.

Тоесть на выходе должны получить вот эту строку - `car was driving car was driving`

И нужно использовать не больше одного цикла. Регулярное выражение тоже подойдет.

Для наглядности скажу что ՝explode՝, `implode` то же циклы.

Как можно это сделать на `php`.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/6MrrjQ/1 - набросал пример, можете попробовать отрегулировать под свои потребности

Comment: `preg_replace('~\b(\w+)\b(?:\s*\1\b)+~u', '$1', 'car car was driving car was driving');`

Comment: при условии, что текст юникод или латиница, ибо \b и \w не сработают. Вот как выше товарищ забыл флаг юникода добавить в регексп - для кириллицы \b и \p{L} вряд ли сработают иначе.

Comment: Что за капризы, "использовать не больше одного цикла"?

Comment: @Ипатьев Если задача токова это не каприз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наконец то нашел решение этой задачи.

Вот примерно так.

Если буду другие варианты, с удовольствием посмотрю.

```
$string = "car car was driving car was was driving";
$outputString = "";
$word = "";
$prevWord = "";

for ($i = 0; $i <= strlen($string); $i++) {
    $char = $i < strlen($string) ? $string[$i] : " ";

    if ($char !== " ") {
        $word .= $char;
    } else {
        if ($word !== $prevWord) {
            $outputString .= $word !== "" ? " " . $word : $word;
        }
        $prevWord = $word;
        $word = "";
    }
}
echo $outputString;
```

Comment: `explode` для разбития строки по разделителю уже изобретен. Как только в исходную строку заедут многобайтовые символы - сможешь выкинуть код на помойку.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понял почему вариант с регулярным выражением не устроил, но добавлю как ответ:

```
$str = 'car car was driving car was driving
car was was driving
car was driving driving
один один два три
один два два три три четыре
один два три четыре четыре';

$result = preg_replace('/\b(\p{L}+)(?:\s+\1\b)+/u', "$1", $str);

echo $result;
//car was driving car was driving
//car was driving
//car was driving
//один два три
//один два три четыре
//один два три четыре
```

О регулярном выражении:

```
\b(\p{L}+)(?:\s+\1\b)+
```

`\b` - так называемая граница слова
`(...)` - группа для захвата данных
`\p{L}+` - один и более языковой символ (вон как в комментариях выше товарищ не забыл, что без параметра `u` с кириллицей работать не будет)
`(?:...)` - группа не захватывающая данные, нужна для квантификации, если слово повторяется более 2х раз
`\s+` - один и более пробельных символов, по идее можно заменить на `\h+` - один и более горизонтальных символов, что бы слово на новой строке не учитывалось если такое же есть в конце предыдущей сроки
`\1` - возвращение захватываемой группы, т.е. на это место подставятся данные которые были захвачены в круглых скобках ранее.

Заменяется все на `$1` что так же является данными захваченными в первую группу, что бы осталось одно слово из множества повторяющихся.